# Inserting an element at the beginning of Vector

Tags: java, performance, collections, vector

I am implementing an Android App which receives a json array of Strings from a webservice. This array can be pretty large (more than 500 entries). I am parsing this data into a Vector object. In the app, the user can add strings into this vector, but the strings have to be added at the beginning of it.

Now I am doing the following to achieve it:

```
Collections.reverse(myVector);
myVector.add(newString);
Collections.reverse(myVector);
```

Is there other less expensive way to do this?

thanx

Comment: Vector is obsolete and you should use ArrayList instead - although in this specific case, LinkedList is probably more appropriate as it will give you O(1) insertions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use a [`java.util.LinkedList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html) instead? You can then use `addFirst`, which should be more efficient since it is a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. But I am using Vector because I heard that is more light than other Lists... do you think that with LinkedList my performance will not be affected?
thx again

Comment: I think the opposite is generally true. All Vector operations are synchronized, which you may not need/want (and I believe the reason it is not recommended any more).

Answer (score 1):

Why can't we use Vector.add(index,element) api, with index as 1?

or am i missing something?

Comment: Generally vector adds at the front are inefficient due to the rest of the array being shifted on each insert, if I am not mistaken

Comment: Inserting to the front costs O(n), no bueno!

Comment: agreed. Mine is a costly solution

Answer (score 1):

A faster way would be to insert directly at the beginning of the vector, using [.add(int, E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28int,%20E%29)...

```
myVector.add(0, newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Vector#add(index, element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28int,&20E%29) method.  However, it will still incur the cost of shifting the elements down each time.

However, to avoid the cost as much as possible, then use `Collections.reverse` at the beginning, then *keep* it reversed, and let the user add the strings until they're done.  Adding to the end (appending) will not need to shift existing elements out of the way.  Once they're done, then reverse it one more time to obtain the proper order.  Total reversals -- only 2.

Comment: I think this is likely the best solution to OP's problem

Comment: That's exactly what I posted and what I'm doing now. thank you anyways

Comment: @Perroloco - Not exactly the same.  If I've read your question correctly, you reverse twice for each time the user adds a string.  I'm saying only reverse twice -- before the user starts adding any strings and after the user is finished adding all strings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Vectors? If you use ArrayList you could insert element in front with   `list.add(0, element)`